# SQL Select with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

[image]

The question is "List every course number in which both ‘John Smith’ and ‘Kevin Miller’ are enrolled."

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CourseNumber 
FROM Enrollment 
INNER JOIN Student ON Student.SSN = Enrollment.SSN 
WHERE Student.Name = 'John Smith' 
  AND Student.Name = 'Kevin Miller'
```

but it didn't return anything.

If I change the operator "AND" to "OR", it's going to show 2 courses number which is the wrong answer.

Can anybody help me please? Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please tag SQL request always with your DBMS, because answers may heavily depend on it. In my answer I suggest `INTERSECT` for instance, which is standard SQL and supported by many DBMS, but MySQL for example doesn't. To give you an idea how important the DBMS, here is a site showing a feature comparision: https://www.sql-workbench.eu/dbms_comparison.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of aggregation logic here, because the assertion on both students inherently involves more than one record.  So, a `WHERE` clause by itself won't work.  Here is one common way to approach this:

```
SELECT e.CourseNumber
FROM Enrollment e
INNER JOIN Student s ON s.SSN = e.SSN
WHERE s.Name = IN ('John Smith', 'Kevin Miller')
GROUP BY e.CourseNumber
HAVING MIN(s.Name) <> MAX(s.Name);
```

I prefer the above approach, but you could also use exists logic here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.CourseNumber
FROM Enrollment e
INNER JOIN Student s ON s.SSN = e.SSN
WHERE
    e.Name = 'John Smith' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Enrollment e1
            INNER JOIN Student s1 ON s1.SSN = e1.SSN
            WHERE e1.CourseNumber = e.CourseNumber AND
                  s1.Name = 'Kevin Miller');
```

Comment: what if there are three students for this scenario

Comment: ...then the queries need to change, but that's not the question which was asked, right? `:-)`

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu For the first query, add the third name to the where clause, and instead assert a distinct count of 3.  For the second query, the exists clause needs to also check for the third name.  It's a big rewrite of the answer, hence I preferred to not do it, unless the OP explicitly asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an alternative to Tim's answer: A simple approach is `INTERSECT`.

```
SELECT coursenumber FROM enrollment WHERE ssn = (SELECT ssn FROM Student WHERE name = 'John Smith')
INTERSECT
SELECT coursenumber FROM enrollment WHERE ssn = (SELECT ssn FROM Student WHERE name = 'Kevin Miller')
```

There are some DBMS that don't support `INTERSECT`, though.